# Select use language on shiny dashboard

Tags: r

I need to create an interface where there is a language selection entry, for this I am using the package "shiny.i18n", however I have problems with executing my code.

## SERVER :

```
  i18n <- reactive({

  translator <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = 
   "~/projects/GEOSIMCAST/DATA/translation.json")
  selected <- input$selected_language
  translator$set_translation_language(selected)
  translator
})
```

## UI:

```
  dashboardSidebar(
                  sidebarMenu(
                    menuItem(i18n()$t("Dashboard"), tabName = "dashboard", 
   icon = icon("th")),

                    menuItem("Language", tabName = "language", icon = 
   icon("globe"),
                    radioButtons("selected_language", "Select language:",
                                  c("English" = "en",
                                    "Spanish" = "sp"
                                    ))),

                    menuItem("About", tabName = "about", icon = icon("th"),badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
                  )
                ),
```

## ERROR:

Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: I get the error when applying the function "i18n()$t ..."

Comment: guess you should add at least a few records of the translation.json file to help us understand its structure